# Why mocha tests don't run on Travis, but local?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, mocha.js, travis-ci

I have this - https://github.com/eppz/eppz-js - setup where tests run local just fine (`4 passing`). But deployed **on Travis CI none of the test are runnig** (`0 passing`).

See [`package.json`](https://github.com/eppz/eppz-js/blob/master/package.json), [`Gruntfile.js`](https://github.com/eppz/eppz-js/blob/master/Gruntfile.js), [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/eppz/eppz-js/blob/master/.travis.yml), [Travis builds](https://travis-ci.org/eppz/eppz-js/builds). Can somebody take a brief look on it?

```
// Local

Running "mocha:test" (mocha) task
Testing: Tests/index.html
>> 4 passed! (0.00s)

Done, without errors.

// Travis CI

Running "mocha:test" (mocha) task
>> 0 passed! (0.00s)

Done, without errors.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `Gruntfile.js` references a **`Tests`** directory, but the only directory that exists is **`tests`**.

The filesystem on ***Travis CI is case-sensitive*** (Mac filesystems by default aren't), so either renaming the directory or changing the `Gruntfile.js` should help you run your tests on Travis CI.